# Is really Files.createDirectory() non-blocking?

Tags: java, nio, project-reactor

I've created such method:

```
Flux<GetObjectResponse> download(String bucket, List<String> s3FileNames) {
    String tmpDirName = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    Path dir = Paths.get(tmpDirName);
    if (!Files.exists(dir)) {
        try {
            Files.createDirectory(dir);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return Flux.fromIterable(s3FileNames)
            .flatMap(filename -> Mono.just(GetObjectRequest.builder().bucket(bucket).key(filename).build()))
            .flatMap(getObjectRequest -> Mono.fromFuture(s3AsyncClient.getObject(getObjectRequest, Paths.get(tmpDirName, getObjectRequest.key()))));
}
```

Later I process this reactive stream, but IntelliJ gives me a hint when I call `Files.createDirectory(dir)`:

```
Inappropriate blocking method call less... (Ctrl+1) 
Inspection info: Reports thread-blocking method calls found in a code fragment where a thread should not be blocked
```

Is IntelliJ right? Is NIO blocking when interoperates with files?

Comment: I wouldn't expect such a call to be asynchronous.  Why would it be?  The usual expectation when you're creating a folder is that the folder is going to be immediately available for adding files to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All file operations before NIO2 are synchronous and you can assume the operation has completed by the time the method returns. 
Only TCP sockets and the file watcher had asynchronous operations.

NIO2 added `AsynchronousFileChannel` however it doesn't apply to directories.

Documentation: [Java I/O, NIO, and NIO.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/io/index.html)